# How do I connect microbit with BLE and listen for button press events?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, bluetooth-lowenergy, uart, bbc-microbit

**11/28/2021 Edit :**

If you need to connect your microbit to your computer using Bluetooth Low Energy, and do stuff when the button is clicked. Jump straight and follow [@ukBaz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7721752/ukbaz)'s answer below.

Note: The solution will work perfectly on GNU/Linux, but maybe not so much on Windows.

*Below is the original question of the post. I'm not going to edit it to hide my mistakes.*

---

Summary: I have a microbit connected to a rpi-zero. I coded the microbit, when `A button` is pressed it will then send data through `uart.write` to the rpi-zero.

In this test, the microbit will `uart.write("Test")`, write a "Test" word to the rpi-zero.

My ultimate goal is to use rpi-zero's BLE capabilities to act as a control device with instructions sent from microbit buttons.

I found this [GATT Server Code](https://scribles.net/creating-ble-gatt-server-uart-service-on-raspberry-pi/) written in python for rpi. Which it ran with no problem at all.

The code below will be used for listening to microbit uart service and check whether if data received is `"Test"`:

```
import serial

serialPort = serial.Serial(port = "/dev/ttyACM0", baudrate=115200, bytesize=8, timeout=0.5, stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE)

serialString = " "

(serialPort.in_waiting > 0)

while True:

        serialString = serialPort.readline()

        if serialString == b'Test':
            print("Yes")
        else:
            print("F")
```

But the real problem is when I try to implement this loop code into the GATT server code.

I cannot seem to get my head around on how to pass this value to `self.send_tx`

Moreover, it seems that there is a global loop already in the GATT server code. So I tried to use threading to run both of the functions simultaneously but when I add `self.send_tx("Test")` it will just throw an error `Self is not defined`.

I'm sorry I'm a total noob to coding, does anyone know the possible fix to this? Thank you

Here's the full code:

```
import sys
import threading
import dbus, dbus.mainloop.glib
import serial
from gi.repository import GLib
from example_advertisement import Advertisement
from example_advertisement import register_ad_cb, register_ad_error_cb
from example_gatt_server import Service, Characteristic
from example_gatt_server import register_app_cb, register_app_error_cb

BLUEZ_SERVICE_NAME =           'org.bluez'
DBUS_OM_IFACE =                'org.freedesktop.DBus.ObjectManager'
LE_ADVERTISING_MANAGER_IFACE = 'org.bluez.LEAdvertisingManager1'
GATT_MANAGER_IFACE =           'org.bluez.GattManager1'
GATT_CHRC_IFACE =              'org.bluez.GattCharacteristic1'
UART_SERVICE_UUID =            '6e400001-b5a3-f393-e0a9-e50e24dcca9e'
UART_RX_CHARACTERISTIC_UUID =  '6e400002-b5a3-f393-e0a9-e50e24dcca9e'
UART_TX_CHARACTERISTIC_UUID =  '6e400003-b5a3-f393-e0a9-e50e24dcca9e'
LOCAL_NAME =                   'rpi-gatt-server'
mainloop = None

serialPort = serial.Serial(port = "/dev/ttyACM0", baudrate=115200, bytesize=8, timeout=0.8, stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE)

serialString = " "

(serialPort.in_waiting > 0)

class TxCharacteristic(Characteristic):
    def __init__(self, bus, index, service):
        Characteristic.__init__(self, bus, index, UART_TX_CHARACTERISTIC_UUID,
                                ['notify'], service)
        self.notifying = False
        GLib.io_add_watch(sys.stdin, GLib.IO_IN, self.on_console_input)

    def on_console_input(self, fd, condition):
        s = fd.readline()
        if s.isspace():
            pass
        else:
            self.send_tx(s)
        return True

    def send_tx(self, s):
        if not self.notifying:
            return
        value = []
        for c in s:
            value.append(dbus.Byte(c.encode()))
        self.PropertiesChanged(GATT_CHRC_IFACE, {'Value': value}, [])

    def StartNotify(self):
        if self.notifying:
            print("yes")
            return
        self.notifying = True

    def StopNotify(self):
        if not self.notifying:
            print("no")
            return
        self.notifying = False

class RxCharacteristic(Characteristic):
    def __init__(self, bus, index, service):
        Characteristic.__init__(self, bus, index, UART_RX_CHARACTERISTIC_UUID,
                                ['write'], service)

    def WriteValue(self, value, options):
        print('remote: {}'.format(bytearray(value).decode()))

class UartService(Service):
    def __init__(self, bus, index):
        Service.__init__(self, bus, index, UART_SERVICE_UUID, True)
        self.add_characteristic(TxCharacteristic(bus, 0, self))
        self.add_characteristic(RxCharacteristic(bus, 1, self))

class Application(dbus.service.Object):
    def __init__(self, bus):
        self.path = '/'
        self.services = []
        dbus.service.Object.__init__(self, bus, self.path)

    def get_path(self):
        return dbus.ObjectPath(self.path)

    def add_service(self, service):
        self.services.append(service)

    @dbus.service.method(DBUS_OM_IFACE, out_signature='a{oa{sa{sv}}}')
    def GetManagedObjects(self):
        response = {}
        for service in self.services:
            response[service.get_path()] = service.get_properties()
            chrcs = service.get_characteristics()
            for chrc in chrcs:
                response[chrc.get_path()] = chrc.get_properties()
        return response

class UartApplication(Application):
    def __init__(self, bus):
        Application.__init__(self, bus)
        self.add_service(UartService(bus, 0))

class UartAdvertisement(Advertisement):
    def __init__(self, bus, index):
        Advertisement.__init__(self, bus, index, 'peripheral')
        self.add_service_uuid(UART_SERVICE_UUID)
        self.add_local_name(LOCAL_NAME)
        self.include_tx_power = True

def find_adapter(bus):
    remote_om = dbus.Interface(bus.get_object(BLUEZ_SERVICE_NAME, '/'),
                               DBUS_OM_IFACE)
    objects = remote_om.GetManagedObjects()
    for o, props in objects.items():
        if LE_ADVERTISING_MANAGER_IFACE in props and GATT_MANAGER_IFACE in props:
            return o
        print('Skip adapter:', o)
    return None

def check():
    while True:
        serialString = serialPort.readline()
        if serialString == b'Test':
            print("Okay, Test")
            self.send_tx("Test")
        else:
            print("No")

def main():
    global mainloop
    dbus.mainloop.glib.DBusGMainLoop(set_as_default=True)
    bus = dbus.SystemBus()
    adapter = find_adapter(bus)
    if not adapter:
        print('BLE adapter not found')
        return

    service_manager = dbus.Interface(
                                bus.get_object(BLUEZ_SERVICE_NAME, adapter),
                                GATT_MANAGER_IFACE)
    ad_manager = dbus.Interface(bus.get_object(BLUEZ_SERVICE_NAME, adapter),
                                LE_ADVERTISING_MANAGER_IFACE)

    app = UartApplication(bus)
    adv = UartAdvertisement(bus, 0)

    mainloop = GLib.MainLoop()

    service_manager.RegisterApplication(app.get_path(), {},
                                        reply_handler=register_app_cb,
                                        error_handler=register_app_error_cb)
    ad_manager.RegisterAdvertisement(adv.get_path(), {},
                                     reply_handler=register_ad_cb,
                                     error_handler=register_ad_error_cb)

    try:
        mainloop.run()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        adv.Release()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p1 = threading.Thread(target=main)
    p2 = threading.Thread(target=check)
    p1.start()
    p2.start()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this might be an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). What I have understood is that you want to send a button press from the micro:bit to the RPi via Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE). If that is the case, then there is a more efficient way to do this.

In the [Bluetooth Profile](https://lancaster-university.github.io/microbit-docs/resources/bluetooth/bluetooth_profile.html) for the micro:bit there is a button service and a button A status characteristic that can be used. Their UUIDs are:

```py
BTN_SRV = 'E95D9882-251D-470A-A062-FA1922DFA9A8'
BTN_A_STATE = 'E95DDA90-251D-470A-A062-FA1922DFA9A8'
```

You need to set up the GATT server on the micro:bit. The most efficient way to do this is using https://makecode.microbit.org/#editor to create the following:
[image]

If you don't have Bluetooth on the left-hand menu then click on the cog in the top right of the screen, select `Extensions`, and then select `Bluetooth` to replace the `Radio` extension.

The GATT client code on the RPi can be simplified by using the [pydbus](https://pypi.org/project/pydbus/) library for the D-Bus bindings.

With Bluetooth, rather than have a `while` loop and keep polling the micro:bit, it is more efficient to have an event loop that subscribes to notifications from (in this case) the Button A characteristic. The function I have named `btn_handler` is called each time the micro:bit button A is pressed or released.

The code below doesn't do the initial pairing between the micro:bit and the RPi. As pairing is a one-off provisioning step I do that manually.

Here is example python code for the RPi that responses to Button A on the micro:bit being pressed...

```py
from time import sleep
import pydbus
from gi.repository import GLib

DEVICE_ADDR = 'DE:82:35:E7:CE:BE' #  micro:bit address
BTN_A_STATE = 'E95DDA90-251D-470A-A062-FA1922DFA9A8'

# DBus object paths
BLUEZ_SERVICE = 'org.bluez'
ADAPTER_PATH = '/org/bluez/hci0'
device_path = f"{ADAPTER_PATH}/dev_{DEVICE_ADDR.replace(':', '_')}"

# setup dbus
bus = pydbus.SystemBus()
mngr = bus.get(BLUEZ_SERVICE, '/')
adapter = bus.get(BLUEZ_SERVICE, ADAPTER_PATH) 
device = bus.get(BLUEZ_SERVICE, device_path)

device.Connect()

while not device.ServicesResolved:
    sleep(0.5)

def get_characteristic_path(dev_path, uuid):
    """Look up DBus path for characteristic UUID"""
    mng_objs = mngr.GetManagedObjects()
    for path in mng_objs:
        chr_uuid = mng_objs[path].get('org.bluez.GattCharacteristic1', {}).get('UUID')
        if path.startswith(dev_path) and chr_uuid == uuid.casefold():
           return path

# Characteristic DBus information
btn_a_path = get_characteristic_path(device._path, BTN_A_STATE)
btn_a = bus.get(BLUEZ_SERVICE, btn_a_path)
# Read button A without event loop notifications
print(btn_a.ReadValue({}))

# Enable eventloop for notifications
def btn_handler(iface, prop_changed, prop_removed):
    """Notify event handler for button press"""
    if 'Value' in prop_changed:
        new_value = prop_changed['Value']
        print(f"Button A state: {new_value}")
        print(f'As byte: {bytes(new_value)}')
        print(f'As bytearray: {bytearray(new_value)}')
        print(f'As int: {int(new_value[0])}')
        print(f'As bool: {bool(new_value[0])}')

mainloop = GLib.MainLoop()
btn_a.onPropertiesChanged = btn_handler
btn_a.StartNotify()
try:
    mainloop.run()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    mainloop.quit()
    btn_a.StopNotify()
    device.Disconnect()
```

Comment: Woah, such a clear and perfect answer. But sadly, the BLE module on my microbit is damaged so I can only use micropython on it ( USB mode ).

Comment: I hope I'm not necroposting this post. However just one year later, and looking back to your answer. I felt I'm so stupid back then. I agree with you, this is clearly an XY problem. I just tested on my new microbit and your solution works perfectly well, although BlueZ will be limited on GNU/Linux os.

Answer (score 1):

I created a Python package to make it easier to connect to the Bluetooth services of a micro:bit: [kaspersmicrobit](https://github.com/janickr/kaspersmicrobit). It works under linux and windows and comes with [extensive documentation](https://kaspersmicrobit.readthedocs.io/en/stable/).

Listening for button events can be done like this:

```
def pressed(button):
  print(f"button {button} pressed")


with KaspersMicrobit(MICROBIT_BLUETOOTH_ADDRESS) as microbit:
  # listen for button events
  microbit.buttons.on_button_a(press=pressed)
  microbit.buttons.on_button_b(press=pressed)

  time.sleep(15)
```

Listening for UART data can be done like this:

```
def print_received_string(string: str):
  print(f"Received from microbit: '{string}'")


with KaspersMicrobit(MICROBIT_BLUETOOTH_ADDRESS) as microbit:
  # listen for strings sent by the microbit 
  microbit.uart.receive_string(print_received_string)

  # send a string to the microbit
  microbit.uart.send_string("Hi, from python!\n")

  time.sleep(25)
```