# Bluetooth comunitation between Arduino and Raspberry pi 4

Tags: python, arduino, bluetooth, raspberry-pi, serial-port

I'm trying to connect an Arduino (with a 4.0 bluetooth module) and a Raspberry pi 4 (with bluetooth module included).
I just want the Rasp to receive a string and never to send, so thats the arduino sketch:

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
SoftwareSerial bluetooth(2, 3);

void setup() {
  bluetooth.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  delay(500);
  bluetooth.println("string");
}
```

Now, if I try connecting my smartphone with a bluetooth terminal it works fine but when i try doing the same on the Raspberry it doesn't receive any byte.
Here's what i tried:

```
import serial
bluetoothSerial = serial.Serial("/dev/rfcomm0", baudrate=9600)
print(bluetoothSerial.readline())
bluetoothSerial.close()
```

Despite the two devices are paired and connected, after some seconds of receiving nothing it gives me an error saying that `"The Host is down"`.

These are the screenshots of bluetoothctl
[image: screenshot1]

[image]

Comment: Thanks, and what's the port I have to connect? @ukBaz

Comment: I checked those example but there's a problem, as I said in the post I need the raspberry to receive a string while he connects to the arduino. So arduino have to be the server and  at the same time send the string message @ukBaz

Comment: The device you are trying to connect to isn't using Bluetooth Classic and the Serial Port Profile (SPP). It is using BLE with a custom GATT service (`ffe0`) and characteristic (`ffe1`). I am sure there is something on this. Let me take a look.

Comment: You need to create a BLE GATT client (Central role in BLE speak) and I have some examples of doing that:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/63751113/7721752  https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/114175/121848
Using a [generic BLE exploration tool](https://www.nordicsemi.com/Software-and-tools/Development-Tools/nRF-Connect-for-mobile) is often helpful to understand the data structure. If you get stuck, open a new question and I'll try to help