# Python and Bluetooth Low Energy: Is there an alternative to pygatt?

Tags: python, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm trying to communicate with an ESP32 microcontroller and my linux desktop using Bluetooth Low Energy.

Right now I'm using the notification example from https://pypi.org/project/pygatt/ (carefully replacing the MAC address and UUID of course).

The pygatt library runs `gatttool` under the hood, and is pretty flaky. Sometimes the example reports a single value before the program terminates. Sometimes it reports a spate of values and then hangs.

I was wondering if there were any alternatives to pygatt that were more robust?

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/bleak/

Answer (score 1):

gatttool is one of the eight tools that BlueZ [deprecated](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/commit/?id=b1eb2c4cd057624312e0412f6c4be000f7fc3617).

BlueZ publishes an API using D-Bus and there are various [D-Bus bindings for Python](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/DBusBindings/)

For a BLE client you will need the following API parts of BlueZ:

- https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/doc/adapter-api.txt
- https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/doc/device-api.txt
- https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/doc/gatt-api.txt

An example of how to do this with [pydbus](https://pypi.org/project/pydbus/) is at:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/63751113/7721752

There are also a number of other BLE Python libraries available on PyPI but not all of them built using the BlueZ supported D-Bus API.