# Bleak find device only when runing bluetoothctl power on & scan on

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm using Xiaomi temperature and humidity sensor with custom firmware who tells me every 1 min the data when the device is connected.

My problem, normal Bleak find the devices only when I did in a second window the following:

```
bluetoothctl 
power on
scan on
```

When I exit bluetoothctl the python script don't find it again.
Bleak supply a Discover Script which finds the goods without bluetoothctl but a connection later failed (I've try already mix both scripts)
https://github.com/hbldh/bleak/blob/develop/examples/discover.py

```
from bleak import BleakClient
import asyncio



notify_uuid = "00002a6f-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb"


def callback(sender, data):

    print(sender, data)

def run(addresses):
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

    tasks = asyncio.gather(*(connect_to_device(address) for address in addresses))

    loop.run_until_complete(tasks)


async def connect_to_device(address):
    print("starting", address, "loop")
    async with BleakClient(address, timeout=50.0) as client:

        print("connect to", address)
        try:
            await client.start_notify(notify_uuid, callback)  
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)

    print("disconnect from", address)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    run(
        ["A4:C1:38:82:8A:50"]
    )
```

Debug on with power and scan on

```
starting A4:C1:38:82:8A:50 loop
2021-09-26 08:53:52,614 bleak.backends.bluezdbus.client DEBUG: Connecting to device @ A4:C1:38:82:8A:50 with hci0
2021-09-26 08:53:52,635 bleak.backends.bluezdbus.scanner DEBUG: cached devices: {}
2021-09-26 08:53:54,457 bleak.backends.bluezdbus.scanner DEBUG: received D-Bus signal: org.freedesktop.DBus.ObjectManager.InterfacesAdded (/): ['/org/bluez/hci0/dev_A4_C1_38_82_8A_50', {'org.freedesktop.DBus.Introspectable': {}, 'org.bluez.Device1': {'Address': <dbus_next.signature.Variant ('s', A4:C1:38:82:8A:50)>, 'AddressType': <dbus_next.signature.Variant ('s', public)>, 'Name': <dbus_next.signature.Variant ('s', ATC_828A50)>, 'Alias': <dbus_next.signature.Variant ('s', ATC_828A50)>, 'Paired': <dbus_next.signature.Variant ('b', False)>, 'Trusted': <dbus_next.signature.Variant ('b', False)>, 'Blocked': <dbus_next.signature.Variant ('b', False)>, 'LegacyPairing': <dbus_next.signature.Variant ('b', False)>, 'RSSI': <dbus_next.signature.Variant ('n', -53)>, 'Connected': <dbus_next.signature.Variant ('b', False)>, 'UUIDs': <dbus_next.signature.Variant ('as', [])>, 'Adapter': <dbus_next.signature.Variant ('o', /org/bluez/hci0)>, 'ServiceData': <dbus_next.signature.Variant ('a{sv}', {'0000181a-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb': <dbus_next.signature.Variant ('ay', b'\xa4\xc18\x82\x8aP\x00\xe8:d\x0ca\x81')>})>, 'ServicesResolved': <dbus_next.signature.Variant ('b', False)>}, 'org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties': {}}]
2021-09-26 08:54:00,157 bleak.backends.bluezdbus.client DEBUG: received D-Bus signal: org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties.PropertiesChanged (/org/bluez/hci0/dev_A4_C1_38_82_8A_50): ['org.bluez.Device1', {'Connected': <dbus_next.signature.Variant ('b', True)>}, []]
2021-09-26 08:54:00,221 bleak.backends.bluezdbus.client DEBUG: Connection successful (/org/bluez/hci0/dev_A4_C1_38_82_8A_50)
2021-09-26 08:54:00,221 bleak.backends.bluezdbus.client DEBUG: Waiting for ServicesResolved (/org/bluez/hci0/dev_A4_C1_38_82_8A_50)
2021-09-26 08:54:01,237 bleak.backends.bluezdbus.client DEBUG: received D-Bus signal: org.freedesktop.DBus.ObjectManager.InterfacesAdded (/): ['/org/bluez/hci0/dev_A4_C1_38_82_8A_50/service0008', {'org.freedesktop.DBus.Introspectable': {}, 'org.bluez.GattService1': {'UUID': <dbus_next.signature.Variant ('s', 00001801-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)>, 'Device': <dbus_next.signature.Variant ('o', /org/bluez/hci0/dev_A4_C1_38_82_8A_50)>, 'Primary': <dbus_next.signature.Variant ('b', True)>, 'Includes': <dbus_next.signature.Variant ('ao', [])>}, 'org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties': {}}]
2021-09-26 08:54:01,239 bleak.backends.bluezdbus.client DEBUG: received D-Bus signal: org.freedesktop.DBus.ObjectManager.InterfacesAdded (/): ['/org/bluez/hci0/dev_A4_C1_38_82_8A_50/service0008/char0009', {'org.freedesktop.DBus.Introspectable': {}, 'org.bluez.GattCharacteristic1': {'UUID': <dbus_next.signature.Variant ('s', 00002a05-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)>, 'Service': <dbus_next.signature.Variant ('o', /org/bluez/hci0/dev_A4_C1_38_82_8A_50/service0008)>, 'Value': <dbus_next.signature.Variant ('ay', b'')>, 'Notifying': <dbus_next.signature.Variant ('b', False)>, 'Flags': <dbus_next.signature.Variant ('as', ['indicate'])>}, 'org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties': {}}]
2021-09-26 08:54:01,241 bleak.backends.bluezdbus.client DEBUG: received D-Bus signal: org.freedesktop.DBus.ObjectManager.InterfacesAdded (/): ['/org/bluez/hci0/dev_A4_C1_38_82_8A_50/service0008/char0009/desc000b', {'org.freedesktop.DBus.Introspectable': {}, 'org.bluez.GattDescriptor1': {'UUID': <dbus_next.signature.Variant ('s', 00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)>, 'Characteristic': <dbus_next.signature.Variant ('o', /org/bluez/hci0/dev_A4_C1_38_82_8A_50/service0008/char0009)>, 'Value': <dbus_next.signature.Variant ('ay', b'')>}, 'org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties': {}}]
2021-09-26 08:54:01,243 bleak.backends.bluezdbus.client DEBUG: received D-Bus signal: org.freedesktop.DBus.ObjectManager.InterfacesAdded (/): ['/org/bluez/hci0/dev_A4_C1_38_82_8A_50/service000c', {'org.freedesktop.DBus.Introspectable': {}, 'org.bluez.GattService1': {'UUID': <dbus_next.signature.Variant ('s', 0000180f-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)>, 'Device': <dbus_next.signature.Variant ('o', /org/bluez/hci0/dev_A4_C1_38_82_8A_50)>, 'Primary': <dbus_next.signature.Variant ('b', True)>, 'Includes': <dbus_next.signature.Variant ('ao', [])>}, 'org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties': {}}]
2021-09-26 08:54:01,245 bleak.backends.bluezdbus.client DEBUG: received D-Bus signal: org.freedesktop.DBus.ObjectManager.InterfacesAdded (/): ['/org/bluez/hci0/dev_A4_C1_38_82_8A_50/service000c/char000d', {'org.freedesktop.DBus.Introspectable': {}, 'org.bluez.GattCharacteristic1': {'UUID': <dbus_next.signature.Variant ('s', 00002a19-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)>, 'Service': <dbus_next.signature.Variant ('o', /org/bluez/hci0/dev_A4_C1_38_82_8A_50/service000c)>, 'Value': <dbus_next.signature.Variant ('ay', b'')>, 'Notifying': <dbus_next.signature.Variant ('b', False)>, 'Flags': <dbus_next.signature.Variant ('as', ['read', 'notify'])>, 'NotifyAcquired': <dbus_next.signature.Variant ('b', False)>}, 'org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties': {}}]
2021-09-26 08:54:01,246 bleak.backends.bluezdbus.client DEBUG: received D-Bus signal: org.freedesktop.DBus.ObjectManager.InterfacesAdded (/): ['/org/bluez/hci0/dev_A4_C1_38_82_8A_50/service000c/char000d/desc000f', {'org.freedesktop.DBus.Introspectable': {}, 'org.bluez.GattDescriptor1': {'UUID': <dbus_next.signature.Variant ('s', 00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)>, 'Characteristic': <dbus_next.signature.Variant ('o', /org/bluez/hci0/dev_A4_C1_38_82_8A_50/service000c/char000d)>, 'Value': <dbus_next.signature.Variant ('ay', b'')>}, 'org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties': {}}]
2021-09-26 08:54:01,248 bleak.backends.bluezdbus.client DEBUG: received D-Bus signal: org.freedesktop.DBus.ObjectManager.InterfacesAdded (/): ['/org/bluez/hci0/dev_A4_C1_38_82_8A_50/service0010', {'org.freedesktop.DBus.Introspectable': {}, 'org.bluez.GattService1': {'UUID': <dbus_next.signature.Variant ('s', 0000181a-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)>, 'Device': <dbus_next.signature.Variant ('o', /org/bluez/hci0/dev_A4_C1_38_82_8A_50)>, 'Primary': <dbus_next.signature.Variant ('b', True)>, 'Includes': <dbus_next.signature.Variant ('ao', [])>}, 'org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties': {}}]
2021-09-26 08:54:01,250 bleak.backends.bluezdbus.client DEBUG: received D-Bus signal: org.freedesktop.DBus.ObjectManager.InterfacesAdded (/): ['/org/bluez/hci0/dev_A4_C1_38_82_8A_50/service0010/char0011', {'org.freedesktop.DBus.Introspectable': {}, 'org.bluez.GattCharacteristic1': {'UUID': <dbus_next.signature.Variant ('s', 00002a1f-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)>, 'Service': <dbus_next.signature.Variant ('o', /org/bluez/hci0/dev_A4_C1_38_82_8A_50/service0010)>, 'Value': <dbus_next.signature.Variant ('ay', b'')>, 'Notifying': <dbus_next.signature.Variant ('b', False)>, 'Flags': <dbus_next.signature.Variant ('as', ['read', 'notify'])>, 'NotifyAcquired': <dbus_next.signature.Variant ('b', False)>}, 'org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties': {}}]
2021-09-26 08:54:01,251 bleak.backends.bluezdbus.client DEBUG: received D-Bus signal: org.freedesktop.DBus.ObjectManager.InterfacesAdded (/): ['/org/bluez/hci0/dev_A4_C1_38_82_8A_50/service0010/char0011/desc0013', {'org.freedesktop.DBus.Introspectable': {}, 'org.bluez.GattDescriptor1': {'UUID': <dbus_next.signature.Variant ('s', 00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)>, 'Characteristic': <dbus_next.signature.Variant ('o', /org/bluez/hci0/dev_A4_C1_38_82_8A_50/service0010/char0011)>, 'Value': <dbus_next.signature.Variant ('ay', b'')>}, 'org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties': {}}]
2021-09-26 08:54:01,253 bleak.backends.bluezdbus.client DEBUG: received D-Bus signal: org.freedesktop.DBus.ObjectManager.InterfacesAdded (/): ['/org/bluez/hci0/dev_A4_C1_38_82_8A_50/service0010/char0014', {'org.freedesktop.DBus.Introspectable': {}, 'org.bluez.GattCharacteristic1': {'UUID': <dbus_next.signature.Variant ('s', 00002a6f-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)>, 'Service': <dbus_next.signature.Variant ('o', /org/bluez/hci0/dev_A4_C1_38_82_8A_50/service0010)>, 'Value': <dbus_next.signature.Variant ('ay', b'')>, 'Notifying': <dbus_next.signature.Variant ('b', False)>, 'Flags': <dbus_next.signature.Variant ('as', ['read', 'notify'])>, 'NotifyAcquired': <dbus_next.signature.Variant ('b', False)>}, 'org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties': {}}]
2021-09-26 08:54:01,254 bleak.backends.bluezdbus.client DEBUG: received D-Bus signal: org.freedesktop.DBus.ObjectManager.InterfacesAdded (/): ['/org/bluez/hci0/dev_A4_C1_38_82_8A_50/service0010/char0014/desc0016', {'org.freedesktop.DBus.Introspectable': {}, 'org.bluez.GattDescriptor1': {'UUID': <dbus_next.signature.Variant ('s', 00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)>, 'Characteristic': <dbus_next.signature.Variant ('o', /org/bluez/hci0/dev_A4_C1_38_82_8A_50/service0010/char0014)>, 'Value': <dbus_next.signature.Variant ('ay', b'')>}, 'org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties': {}}]
2021-09-26 08:54:01,255 bleak.backends.bluezdbus.client DEBUG: received D-Bus signal: org.freedesktop.DBus.ObjectManager.InterfacesAdded (/): ['/org/bluez/hci0/dev_A4_C1_38_82_8A_50/service0017', {'org.freedesktop.DBus.Introspectable': {}, 'org.bluez.GattService1': {'UUID': <dbus_next.signature.Variant ('s', 00010203-0405-0607-0809-0a0b0c0d1912)>, 'Device': <dbus_next.signature.Variant ('o', /org/bluez/hci0/dev_A4_C1_38_82_8A_50)>, 'Primary': <dbus_next.signature.Variant ('b', True)>, 'Includes': <dbus_next.signature.Variant ('ao', [])>}, 'org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties': {}}]
2021-09-26 08:54:01,257 bleak.backends.bluezdbus.client DEBUG: received D-Bus signal: org.freedesktop.DBus.ObjectManager.InterfacesAdded (/): ['/org/bluez/hci0/dev_A4_C1_38_82_8A_50/service0017/char0018', {'org.freedesktop.DBus.Introspectable': {}, 'org.bluez.GattCharacteristic1': {'UUID': <dbus_next.signature.Variant ('s', 00010203-0405-0607-0809-0a0b0c0d2b12)>, 'Service': <dbus_next.signature.Variant ('o', /org/bluez/hci0/dev_A4_C1_38_82_8A_50/service0017)>, 'Value': <dbus_next.signature.Variant ('ay', b'')>, 'Flags': <dbus_next.signature.Variant ('as', ['read', 'write-without-response'])>, 'WriteAcquired': <dbus_next.signature.Variant ('b', False)>}, 'org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties': {}}]
2021-09-26 08:54:01,258 bleak.backends.bluezdbus.client DEBUG: received D-Bus signal: org.freedesktop.DBus.ObjectManager.InterfacesAdded (/): ['/org/bluez/hci0/dev_A4_C1_38_82_8A_50/service0017/char0018/desc001a', {'org.freedesktop.DBus.Introspectable': {}, 'org.bluez.GattDescriptor1': {'UUID': <dbus_next.signature.Variant ('s', 00002901-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)>, 'Characteristic': <dbus_next.signature.Variant ('o', /org/bluez/hci0/dev_A4_C1_38_82_8A_50/service0017/char0018)>, 'Value': <dbus_next.signature.Variant ('ay', b'')>}, 'org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties': {}}]
2021-09-26 08:54:01,259 bleak.backends.bluezdbus.client DEBUG: received D-Bus signal: org.freedesktop.DBus.ObjectManager.InterfacesAdded (/): ['/org/bluez/hci0/dev_A4_C1_38_82_8A_50/service001b', {'org.freedesktop.DBus.Introspectable': {}, 'org.bluez.GattService1': {'UUID': <dbus_next.signature.Variant ('s', 00001f10-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)>, 'Device': <dbus_next.signature.Variant ('o', /org/bluez/hci0/dev_A4_C1_38_82_8A_50)>, 'Primary': <dbus_next.signature.Variant ('b', True)>, 'Includes': <dbus_next.signature.Variant ('ao', [])>}, 'org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties': {}}]
2021-09-26 08:54:01,261 bleak.backends.bluezdbus.client DEBUG: received D-Bus signal: org.freedesktop.DBus.ObjectManager.InterfacesAdded (/): ['/org/bluez/hci0/dev_A4_C1_38_82_8A_50/service001b/char001c', {'org.freedesktop.DBus.Introspectable': {}, 'org.bluez.GattCharacteristic1': {'UUID': <dbus_next.signature.Variant ('s', 00001f1f-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)>, 'Service': <dbus_next.signature.Variant ('o', /org/bluez/hci0/dev_A4_C1_38_82_8A_50/service001b)>, 'Value': <dbus_next.signature.Variant ('ay', b'')>, 'Notifying': <dbus_next.signature.Variant ('b', False)>, 'Flags': <dbus_next.signature.Variant ('as', ['write-without-response', 'notify'])>, 'WriteAcquired': <dbus_next.signature.Variant ('b', False)>, 'NotifyAcquired': <dbus_next.signature.Variant ('b', False)>}, 'org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties': {}}]
2021-09-26 08:54:01,262 bleak.backends.bluezdbus.client DEBUG: received D-Bus signal: org.freedesktop.DBus.ObjectManager.InterfacesAdded (/): ['/org/bluez/hci0/dev_A4_C1_38_82_8A_50/service001b/char001c/desc001e', {'org.freedesktop.DBus.Introspectable': {}, 'org.bluez.GattDescriptor1': {'UUID': <dbus_next.signature.Variant ('s', 00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)>, 'Characteristic': <dbus_next.signature.Variant ('o', /org/bluez/hci0/dev_A4_C1_38_82_8A_50/service001b/char001c)>, 'Value': <dbus_next.signature.Variant ('ay', b'')>}, 'org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties': {}}]
2021-09-26 08:54:01,263 bleak.backends.bluezdbus.client DEBUG: received D-Bus signal: org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties.PropertiesChanged (/org/bluez/hci0/dev_A4_C1_38_82_8A_50): ['org.bluez.Device1', {'UUIDs': <dbus_next.signature.Variant ('as', ['00001800-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb', '00001801-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb', '0000180f-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb', '0000181a-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb', '00001f10-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb', '00010203-0405-0607-0809-0a0b0c0d1912'])>, 'ServicesResolved': <dbus_next.signature.Variant ('b', True)>}, []]
connect to A4:C1:38:82:8A:50
2021-09-26 08:54:01,427 bleak.backends.bluezdbus.client DEBUG: received D-Bus signal: org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties.PropertiesChanged (/org/bluez/hci0/dev_A4_C1_38_82_8A_50): ['org.bluez.Device1', {'Name': <dbus_next.signature.Variant ('s', ATC)>, 'Alias': <dbus_next.signature.Variant ('s', ATC)>}, []]
2021-09-26 08:54:01,600 bleak.backends.bluezdbus.client DEBUG: received D-Bus signal: org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties.PropertiesChanged (/org/bluez/hci0/dev_A4_C1_38_82_8A_50/service0010/char0014): ['org.bluez.GattCharacteristic1', {'Notifying': <dbus_next.signature.Variant ('b', True)>}, []]
2021-09-26 08:54:01,601 bleak.backends.bluezdbus.client DEBUG: Disconnecting (/org/bluez/hci0/dev_A4_C1_38_82_8A_50)
2021-09-26 08:54:04,634 bleak.backends.bluezdbus.client DEBUG: received D-Bus signal: org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties.PropertiesChanged (/org/bluez/hci0/dev_A4_C1_38_82_8A_50): ['org.bluez.Device1', {'ServicesResolved': <dbus_next.signature.Variant ('b', False)>}, []]
2021-09-26 08:54:04,636 bleak.backends.bluezdbus.client DEBUG: received D-Bus signal: org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties.PropertiesChanged (/org/bluez/hci0/dev_A4_C1_38_82_8A_50): ['org.bluez.Device1', {'Connected': <dbus_next.signature.Variant ('b', False)>}, []]
2021-09-26 08:54:04,637 bleak.backends.bluezdbus.client DEBUG: Device disconnected (/org/bluez/hci0/dev_A4_C1_38_82_8A_50)
2021-09-26 08:54:04,637 bleak.backends.bluezdbus.client DEBUG: _remove_signal_handlers(/org/bluez/hci0/dev_A4_C1_38_82_8A_50)
2021-09-26 08:54:04,643 bleak.backends.bluezdbus.client DEBUG: _disconnect_message_bus(/org/bluez/hci0/dev_A4_C1_38_82_8A_50)
disconnect from A4:C1:38:82:8A:50
```

And withouth:

```
starting A4:C1:38:82:8A:50 loop
2021-09-26 08:55:30,458 bleak.backends.bluezdbus.client DEBUG: Connecting to device @ A4:C1:38:82:8A:50 with hci0
2021-09-26 08:55:30,478 bleak.backends.bluezdbus.scanner DEBUG: cached devices: {}
2021-09-26 08:55:31,351 bleak.backends.bluezdbus.scanner DEBUG: received D-Bus signal: org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties.PropertiesChanged (/org/bluez/hci0): ['org.bluez.Adapter1', {'Discovering': <dbus_next.signature.Variant ('b', True)>}, []]
2021-09-26 08:55:31,595 bleak.backends.bluezdbus.scanner DEBUG: received D-Bus signal: org.freedesktop.DBus.ObjectManager.InterfacesAdded (/): ['/org/bluez/hci0/dev_A4_C1_38_82_8A_50', {'org.freedesktop.DBus.Introspectable': {}, 'org.bluez.Device1': {'Address': <dbus_next.signature.Variant ('s', A4:C1:38:82:8A:50)>, 'AddressType': <dbus_next.signature.Variant ('s', public)>, 'Name': <dbus_next.signature.Variant ('s', ATC_828A50)>, 'Alias': <dbus_next.signature.Variant ('s', ATC_828A50)>, 'Paired': <dbus_next.signature.Variant ('b', False)>, 'Trusted': <dbus_next.signature.Variant ('b', False)>, 'Blocked': <dbus_next.signature.Variant ('b', False)>, 'LegacyPairing': <dbus_next.signature.Variant ('b', False)>, 'RSSI': <dbus_next.signature.Variant ('n', -66)>, 'Connected': <dbus_next.signature.Variant ('b', False)>, 'UUIDs': <dbus_next.signature.Variant ('as', [])>, 'Adapter': <dbus_next.signature.Variant ('o', /org/bluez/hci0)>, 'ServiceData': <dbus_next.signature.Variant ('a{sv}', {'0000181a-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb': <dbus_next.signature.Variant ('ay', b'\xa4\xc18\x82\x8aP\x00\xe8:d\x0c^\x83')>})>, 'ServicesResolved': <dbus_next.signature.Variant ('b', False)>}, 'org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties': {}}]
2021-09-26 08:55:31,630 bleak.backends.bluezdbus.client DEBUG: org.bluez.Device1 object not found, trying org.bluez.Adapter1.ConnectDevice (/org/bluez/hci0/dev_A4_C1_38_82_8A_50)
2021-09-26 08:55:31,633 bleak.backends.bluezdbus.client DEBUG: org.bluez.Adapter1.ConnectDevice not found (/org/bluez/hci0/dev_A4_C1_38_82_8A_50), try enabling bluetoothd --experimental
2021-09-26 08:55:31,633 bleak.backends.bluezdbus.client DEBUG: _remove_signal_handlers(/org/bluez/hci0/dev_A4_C1_38_82_8A_50)
2021-09-26 08:55:31,639 bleak.backends.bluezdbus.client DEBUG: _disconnect_message_bus(/org/bluez/hci0/dev_A4_C1_38_82_8A_50)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/www/bt2/3.py", line 37, in <module>
    run(
  File "/var/www/bt2/3.py", line 20, in run
    loop.run_until_complete(tasks)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/asyncio/base_events.py", line 642, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "/var/www/bt2/3.py", line 25, in connect_to_device
    async with BleakClient(address, timeout=50.0) as client:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/bleak/backends/client.py", line 61, in __aenter__
    await self.connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/bleak/backends/bluezdbus/client.py", line 236, in connect
    raise BleakError(
bleak.exc.BleakError: Device with address A4:C1:38:82:8A:50 could not be found. Try increasing `timeout` value or moving the device closer.
```

Now with the experimental flag

```
starting A4:C1:38:82:8A:50 loop
2021-09-26 09:57:10,951 bleak.backends.bluezdbus.client DEBUG: Connecting to device @ A4:C1:38:82:8A:50 with hci0
2021-09-26 09:57:10,981 bleak.backends.bluezdbus.scanner DEBUG: cached devices: {'/org/bluez/hci0/dev_A4_C1_38_82_8A_50': {'Address': 'A4:C1:38:82:8A:50', 'AddressType': 'public', 'Name': 'ATC', 'Alias': 'ATC', 'Paired': False, 'Trusted': False, 'Blocked': False, 'LegacyPairing': False, 'Connected': True, 'UUIDs': ['00001800-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb', '00001801-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb', '0000180f-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb', '0000181a-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb', '00001f10-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb', '00010203-0405-0607-0809-0a0b0c0d1912'], 'Adapter': '/org/bluez/hci0', 'ServiceData': {'0000181a-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb': b'\xa4\xc18\x82\x8aP\x00\xe3<d\x0c^\xc5'}, 'ServicesResolved': True}}
2021-09-26 09:57:11,442 bleak.backends.bluezdbus.scanner DEBUG: received D-Bus signal: org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties.PropertiesChanged (/org/bluez/hci0): ['org.bluez.Adapter1', {'Discovering': <dbus_next.signature.Variant ('b', True)>}, []]
2021-09-26 09:57:15,774 bleak.backends.bluezdbus.scanner DEBUG: received D-Bus signal: org.freedesktop.DBus.ObjectManager.InterfacesAdded (/): ['/org/bluez/hci0/dev_A4_C1_38_A2_65_F9', {'org.freedesktop.DBus.Introspectable': {}, 'org.bluez.Device1': {'Address': <dbus_next.signature.Variant ('s', A4:C1:38:A2:65:F9)>, 'AddressType': <dbus_next.signature.Variant ('s', public)>, 'Name': <dbus_next.signature.Variant ('s', ATC_A265F9)>, 'Alias': <dbus_next.signature.Variant ('s', ATC_A265F9)>, 'Paired': <dbus_next.signature.Variant ('b', False)>, 'Trusted': <dbus_next.signature.Variant ('b', False)>, 'Blocked': <dbus_next.signature.Variant ('b', False)>, 'LegacyPairing': <dbus_next.signature.Variant ('b', False)>, 'RSSI': <dbus_next.signature.Variant ('n', -55)>, 'Connected': <dbus_next.signature.Variant ('b', False)>, 'UUIDs': <dbus_next.signature.Variant ('as', [])>, 'Adapter': <dbus_next.signature.Variant ('o', /org/bluez/hci0)>, 'ServiceData': <dbus_next.signature.Variant ('a{sv}', {'0000181a-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb': <dbus_next.signature.Variant ('ay', b'\xa4\xc18\xa2e\xf9\x00\xe4<d\x0cr\xbd')>})>, 'ServicesResolved': <dbus_next.signature.Variant ('b', False)>}, 'org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties': {}}]
2021-09-26 09:57:16,367 bleak.backends.bluezdbus.scanner DEBUG: received D-Bus signal: org.freedesktop.DBus.ObjectManager.InterfacesAdded (/): ['/org/bluez/hci0/dev_A4_C1_38_83_74_A3', {'org.freedesktop.DBus.Introspectable': {}, 'org.bluez.Device1': {'Address': <dbus_next.signature.Variant ('s', A4:C1:38:83:74:A3)>, 'AddressType': <dbus_next.signature.Variant ('s', public)>, 'Name': <dbus_next.signature.Variant ('s', ATC_8374A3)>, 'Alias': <dbus_next.signature.Variant ('s', ATC_8374A3)>, 'Paired': <dbus_next.signature.Variant ('b', False)>, 'Trusted': <dbus_next.signature.Variant ('b', False)>, 'Blocked': <dbus_next.signature.Variant ('b', False)>, 'LegacyPairing': <dbus_next.signature.Variant ('b', False)>, 'RSSI': <dbus_next.signature.Variant ('n', -65)>, 'Connected': <dbus_next.signature.Variant ('b', False)>, 'UUIDs': <dbus_next.signature.Variant ('as', [])>, 'Adapter': <dbus_next.signature.Variant ('o', /org/bluez/hci0)>, 'ServiceData': <dbus_next.signature.Variant ('a{sv}', {'0000181a-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb': <dbus_next.signature.Variant ('ay', b'\xa4\xc18\x83t\xa3\x00\xe8<d\x0c9\xbf')>})>, 'ServicesResolved': <dbus_next.signature.Variant ('b', False)>}, 'org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties': {}}]
2021-09-26 09:57:18,255 bleak.backends.bluezdbus.scanner DEBUG: received D-Bus signal: org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties.PropertiesChanged (/org/bluez/hci0/dev_A4_C1_38_83_74_A3): ['org.bluez.Device1', {'RSSI': <dbus_next.signature.Variant ('n', -66)>}, []]
2021-09-26 09:57:19,553 bleak.backends.bluezdbus.scanner DEBUG: received D-Bus signal: org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties.PropertiesChanged (/org/bluez/hci0/dev_A4_C1_38_A2_65_F9): ['org.bluez.Device1', {'RSSI': <dbus_next.signature.Variant ('n', -55)>}, []]
2021-09-26 09:57:20,146 bleak.backends.bluezdbus.scanner DEBUG: received D-Bus signal: org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties.PropertiesChanged (/org/bluez/hci0/dev_A4_C1_38_83_74_A3): ['org.bluez.Device1', {'RSSI': <dbus_next.signature.Variant ('n', -66)>}, []]
2021-09-26 09:57:21,434 bleak.backends.bluezdbus.scanner DEBUG: received D-Bus signal: org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties.PropertiesChanged (/org/bluez/hci0/dev_A4_C1_38_A2_65_F9): ['org.bluez.Device1', {'RSSI': <dbus_next.signature.Variant ('n', -57)>}, []]
2021-09-26 09:57:21,460 bleak.backends.bluezdbus.scanner DEBUG: received D-Bus signal: org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties.PropertiesChanged (/org/bluez/hci0/dev_A4_C1_38_A2_65_F9): ['org.bluez.Device1', {}, ['RSSI']]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/www/bt2/3.py", line 37, in <module>
    run(
  File "/var/www/bt2/3.py", line 20, in run
    loop.run_until_complete(tasks)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/asyncio/base_events.py", line 642, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "/var/www/bt2/3.py", line 25, in connect_to_device
    async with BleakClient(address, timeout=50.0) as client:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/bleak/backends/client.py", line 61, in __aenter__
    await self.connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/bleak/backends/bluezdbus/client.py", line 137, in connect
    raise BleakError(
bleak.exc.BleakError: Device with address A4:C1:38:82:8A:50 was not found.
```

Comment: Can you update your question with some more details such as what error message you are getting? In the Bleak documentation there is a section on [troubleshooting](https://bleak.readthedocs.io/en/latest/troubleshooting.html), have you tried any of the suggestions in there?  Have you looked at using a different library? There is an example at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63751113/7721752

Comment: hello @ukBaz no but i will try it later, I've updated the question and added the debug logs, the error u asked was " Device with address A4:C1:38:82:8A:50 could not be found. Try increasing `timeout` value or moving the device closer."

Answer (score 1):

Looking through the debug messages, it shows that the `cached devices` is empty:

```
2021-09-26 08:55:30,478 bleak.backends.bluezdbus.scanner DEBUG: cached devices: {}
```

This should be the same result as if you do `bluetoothctl devices`.

When you do a device discover/scan (e.g. a `scan` inside `bluetoothctl`) you will see devices added to the cache. These devices will be deleted from the cache if they are not interacted with in some way within a certain time period. To stop your device being deleted from the cache you can, inside `bluetoothctl`, do a `connect A4:C1:38:82:8A:50`. This should stop the device being deleted from the cache.

Bleak tries to workaround the feature of unused device being removed from the cache by using `ConnectDevice`. However it fails because the BlueZ experimental functionality is not enabled on your system.

```
2021-09-26 08:55:31,630 bleak.backends.bluezdbus.client DEBUG: org.bluez.Device1 object not found, trying org.bluez.Adapter1.ConnectDevice (/org/bluez/hci0/dev_A4_C1_38_82_8A_50)
2021-09-26 08:55:31,633 bleak.backends.bluezdbus.client DEBUG: org.bluez.Adapter1.ConnectDevice not found (/org/bluez/hci0/dev_A4_C1_38_82_8A_50), try enabling bluetoothd --experimental
```

`ConnectDevice` is [not meant for production use](https://marc.info/?l=linux-bluetooth&m=159013573912327&w=2) and so sits behind the `--experimental` flag on `bluetoothd`. To switch this on by default edit the `/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service` file by adding the `--experimental` flag to `bluetoothd`

```
sudo sed -i '/^ExecStart.*bluetoothd\s*$/ s/$/ --experimental/' /lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service
```

Personally I would not enable the experimental functionality, and do a `bluetoothctl` "scan-connect-disconnect" as a one-time provisioning step when adding a new device.

Comment: the problem is, this will not hold in the cache, when i exit bluetoothctl the device is again not found. "power on, scan on,  connect A4:C1:38:82:8A:50
Device A4:C1:38:82:8A:50 not available", it will first list after i start the python script

Comment: Then you will need to look for more debug information from `sudo btmon`, `journalctl -f -u bluetooth`, and `sudo busctl monitor org.bluez`. You might also want to look in the BlueZ config file in  `/etc/bluetooth/main.conf` and compare it with the one in the source tree https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/src/main.conf. Also, is the cache being created in `/var/lib/bluetooth/`