# Bluetooth Monitoring Program Lag Issue (btmon and python3)

Tags: python-3.x, bluetooth

I'm currently developing a Python program to monitor a Bluetooth device by using btmon. However, I've encountered an issue where there seems to be a delay between the keypress on my Bluetooth device (which registers instantaneously in btmon) and the output in my Python program.

Essentially I am trying to read the raw data off my BT device and trigger an event when pressing LEFT or RIGHT. Its a BT ring for my ereader ;)

I have 2 terminals open one with my program which in its troubleshooting form is only meant to print the data from BTmon. BTmon shows instant feedback on the keypress and my program ONLY shows the keypresses after I press it atleast twice.

When it then finally prints it shows all the keypresses at once with the timestamp of the latest keypress.

Example I press once at 1300 and it will never print in my program

I press once again at say 1305 and it will show up as two keypresses.

If i press with a second of eachother I will need a third keypress.

This behavior suggest some sort of buffer - Or is there something i am completely missing?

What I've Tried:

Case 1: Using subprocess.Popen to run btmon and printing its output line by line.

Case 2: Similar to Case 1, but using a function to continuously print btmon output.

Case 3: Attempting to process lines from btmon output as soon as they are available using iter.

Case 4: Using subprocess.Popen with PIPE and universal_newlines=True to print output line by line.

Case 5: Utilizing a loop with subprocess.Popen to print btmon output continuously until finished.

**All with the exact same outcome.**

Request for Assistance:

I'm seeking help to understand why there's a lag between the Bluetooth device keypress and the output in my Python program. Is there something I'm missing in my approach or is there a better way to capture real-time data from btmon in Python?

```
Case 1:
import subprocess

def run_btmon():
    btmon_process = subprocess.Popen(["sudo", "btmon"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.DEVNULL, text=True)

    for line in btmon_process.stdout:
        print(line.strip())

def main():
    run_btmon()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

Case 2:
import subprocess

def capture_bluetooth_data():
    btmon_process = subprocess.Popen(["sudo", "btmon"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, text=True)
    
    for line in btmon_process.stdout:
        print(line.strip())

def main():
    capture_bluetooth_data()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

Case 3:
import subprocess

def capture_bluetooth_data():
    btmon_process = subprocess.Popen(["sudo", "btmon"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, text=True)
    
    for line in iter(btmon_process.stdout.readline, ""):
        print(line.strip())

def main():
    capture_bluetooth_data()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

Case 4:
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, CalledProcessError

def capture_bluetooth_data():
    with Popen(["sudo", "btmon"], stdout=PIPE, bufsize=1, universal_newlines=True) as p:
        for line in p.stdout:
            print(line.strip())

        if p.returncode != 0:
            raise CalledProcessError(p.returncode, p.args)

def main():
    capture_bluetooth_data()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

Case 5:
import subprocess
import sys

def capture_bluetooth_data():
    process = subprocess.Popen(["sudo", "btmon"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, universal_newlines=True)

    while True:
        nextline = process.stdout.readline()
        if nextline == '' and process.poll() is not None:
            break
        print(nextline.strip())
        sys.stdout.flush()

    output, _ = process.communicate()
    exit_code = process.returncode

    if exit_code != 0:
        raise subprocess.CalledProcessError(exit_code, ["sudo", "btmon"])

def main():
    capture_bluetooth_data()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: There seems to be some known buffering issues with the way you are trying to monitor the BT activity. Is your device sending the information over BLE? You might be better creating a client to read the data. e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/63751113/7721752

Answer (score 0):

The issue you're encountering with the delay between keypresses on your Bluetooth device and the output in your Python program likely stems from buffering in the communication between btmon and your program.
As a solution you can use Non-Blocking I/O with `select`:
Use the select module to implement non-blocking I/O. This allows your program to check for available data from btmon without waiting for a full buffer.
You can also use `sys.stdout.buffer.write(data)` instead of `print(data)` to write data to the standard output in a more fine-grained manner, potentially reducing buffering delays.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately i still seem to struggle with the delay/buffer issue